# Prisma findMany with 2 fields from array

Tags: node.js, database, prisma, prisma2

I am using Prisma and I have two field values that I want to search on

```
const requests = [{ id, cid }, { id, cid }, { id, cid }];
```

I want to search on both fields together but for many.

```
for(request of requests) {
    prisma.user.findFirst({
        where: {
            id: request.id,
            cid: request.cid
        }
    });
}
```

Basically I want to do the above query but for many pairs at once. How to do that?

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for `in` operator.

```js
const requests = [{ id, cid }, { id, cid }, { id, cid }];

const ids = requests.map((request)=>request.id);
const cids = requests.map((request)=>request.cid);

const getUser = await prisma.user.findMany({
  where: {
    id: { in: ids },
    cid: { in: cids }
  },
})
```

Here is a link to `in` operator [documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#in)

Comment: I am asking for data to be used in pairs, not any id and any cid

Comment: what about the cross results of the id and cid? What I mean to say is that we have to search in pairs.